# Using reference breaks mongoose model - Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Concert model:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const concertSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  performer: { type: String, required: true },
  genre: { type: String, required: true },
  price: { type: Number, required: true },
  day: { type: Number, required: true },
  image: { type: String, required: true },
  workshops: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Workshop' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Concert', concertSchema);
```

Workshop model:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const workshopSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  concertId: { type: String, required: true, }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Workshop', workshopSchema)
```

Example of concert data:

```js
{"_id":{"$oid":"652ff8c9474981f1b2c335ca"},"id":{"$numberInt":"2"},"performer":"Rebekah Parker","genre":"R&B","price":{"$numberInt":"25"},"day":{"$numberInt":"2"},"image":"/img/uploads/2f342s4fsdg.jpg","workshops":[{"$oid":"6538f7023ebd4e3eea6c394d"},{"$oid":"6538f9803ebd4e3eea6c3958"},{"$oid":"6538f9ca3ebd4e3eea6c395a"},{"$oid":"6538fa103ebd4e3eea6c395c"}]}
```

When I try to use `await Concert.find().populate('workshops')` I get internal server error. If I don't use `.populate('workshops')` then everything works fine. If I change this line `workshops: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Workshop' }]` to just use `type: String` the concerts collection is returned but workshops property is omitted. I don't really have any idea what is wrong. Workshop IDs in the array are valid and have corresponding data in workshop collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schemas look fine and the sample data for the `workshops` array looks typical. It is likely that your Model is not registered. Try passing the Model with the populate request:

```js
const concert = await Concert.find().populate({ 
   path: 'workshops',
   model: Workshop
});
```

Comment: It works! Thank You so much, I've spent so much time on this but I didn't think of that

Comment: You're welcome. Depending on how your project is structured can mean this is quite a common problem. Glad it helped.